# What is this error?: unbound method requires a vtkRenderingCorePython.vtkAbstractMapper as the first argument

Tags: python, pyqt, vtk

I am using VTK in Python now. And This is the first time I have been programming with Python.
After outputting the 3D object, we want to output the cross section of the object using the `AddClippingPlane` function.
However, the following error will be displayed and it will not be executed:

> TypeError: unbound method requires a
>   vtkRenderingCorePython.vtkAbstractMapper as the first argument.

When you see the attached code, can you tell me what's wrong? I would appreciate a lot your help.

```
import vtk
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import  *
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from foo import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import Qt

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setupUi(self) 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.OpenVTK)     
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(
            QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)


    def OpenVTK(self):
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.frame)
        self.vl = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vl.addWidget(self.vtkWidget)
        self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)
        self.iren = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()

        reader = vtk.vtkDICOMImageReader()
        reader.SetDirectoryName(FilePath)

        reader.Update()
        colors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()
        colors.SetColor("BkgColor", [51, 77, 102, 255])
        boneExtractor = vtk.vtkMarchingCubes()
        boneExtractor.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
        boneExtractor.SetValue(0, 1000)
        boneStripper = vtk.vtkStripper()
        boneStripper.SetInputConnection(boneExtractor.GetOutputPort())
        boneMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        boneMapper.SetInputConnection(boneStripper.GetOutputPort())
        boneMapper.ScalarVisibilityOff()
        plane1 = vtk.vtkPlane()
        plane1.SetOrigin(0.05, 0.0, 0.0)  # [*1]
        plane1.SetNormal(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

        bone = vtk.vtkActor()
        bone.SetMapper(boneMapper)
        bone.GetProperty().SetDiffuseColor(colors.GetColor3d("Ivory"))
        bone = vtk.vtkAbstractMapper.AddClippingPlane(plane1)

        bwLut = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
        bwLut.SetTableRange(0, 2000)
        bwLut.SetSaturationRange(0, 1)
        bwLut.SetHueRange(0, 0)
        bwLut.SetValueRange(0, 1)
        bwLut.Build() 

        sagittalColors = vtk.vtkImageMapToColors()
        sagittalColors.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
        sagittalColors.SetLookupTable(bwLut)
        sagittalColors.Update()

        sagittal = vtk.vtkImageActor()
        sagittal.GetMapper().SetInputConnection(sagittalColors.GetOutputPort())
        sagittal.SetDisplayExtent(250, 250, 0, 501, 0, 500) 

        aCamera = vtk.vtkCamera()
        aCamera.SetViewUp(0, 0, -1)
        aCamera.SetPosition(0, -1, 0)
        aCamera.SetFocalPoint(0, 0, 0)
        aCamera.ComputeViewPlaneNormal()
        aCamera.Azimuth(0.0)
        aCamera.Elevation(0.0)


        self.ren.AddActor(sagittal)
        self.ren.AddActor(bone)
        self.ren.SetActiveCamera(aCamera)
        self.show()
        self.ren.ResetCamera()
        self.frame.setLayout(self.vl)
        aCamera.Dolly(1.0)

        self.ren.ResetCameraClippingRange()
        self.show()
        self.iren.Initialize()
        self.iren.Start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from the line `bone = vtk.vtkAbstractMapper.AddClippingPlane(plane1)`.

`AddClippingPlane()`is an instance method and has to be applied on a object.

It should be something like `boneMapper.AddClippingPlane(plane1)`